# Problems getting the gulp-imagemin to work

Tags: node.js, compiler-errors, gulp

I'm having a hard time getting the gulp-imagemin to work with node v16.8.0 and npm v7.21.1 on my MacOS Big Sur.

Here is an excerpt from my gulpfile.js file:

```
// Include Our tasks.
//
// Each task is broken apart to it's own node module.
// Check out the ./gulp-tasks directory for more.
...
const { compressAssets } = require('./gulp-tasks/compress');
...
// Compress Files
exports.compress = compressAssets;
```

This is my compress.js file:

```
'use strict';

// Include gulp
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');

// Include Our Plugins
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

// Export our tasks.
module.exports = {
  // Compress svg/png/jpg files.
  compressAssets: function() {
    return src([
      './source/patterns/{global,layout,components}/**/*{.png,.jpg,.svg}'
    ])
      .pipe(imagemin())
      .pipe(
        rename(function(path) {
          path.dirname = '';
          return path;
        })
      )
      .pipe(dest('./dist/images'));
  }
};
```

First I get an error message called ERR_REQUIRE_ESM and a message from the compiler that I need to change compress.js and use a dynamic import.
Therefore, I have corrected the line `const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');` to `const imagemin = import('gulp-imagemin');`

But now there is an error message called `TypeError: imagemin is not a function`

I have therefore tried to correct the line `.pipe(imagemin())` to `.pipe(imagemin)` but there is just a new error message:

```
TypeError: dest.on is not a function
```

How do I proceed?